# Getting the Keyboard GO button to act like the Native APP in IONIC2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

When I used the Ionic View Android App, I noticed it has a feature I want. After you enter your email/password, when you hit the Keyboard's GO button, the app acts as if the App Submit button was hit.

How do we setup our apps so that the app Submit thinks it was clicked when the user hits the keyboard GO button?

Thanks..

Comment: Have you tried by using a form and a button with `type="submit"`?

Comment: @sebaferreras : yes, now its work fine... Thanks for Idea.. :)

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: @sebaferreras :thank you again... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me to make the phone keyboard's GO button activate my "Login" Submit button.

```
<form ng-submit="submitLogin()">
    <button type="submit" class="button" ng-click="idSubmit()">
  Login</button>
</form>
```